# MySQL: Syntax error around foreign key assignment

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, syntax

I put the following into DB Fiddle in an attempt to debug it. The error is below

```
Results
Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in
 your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
 MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'references frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons(couponId) on 
delete cascade )' at line 9

// the sql for this error (first table is being referenced in the
// 2nd where the error is
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons (
    couponId mediumint not null auto_increment unique,
    primary key (couponId),
    totalHits mediumint not null,
    isText boolean not null,
    imageUrl text(1000)
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frequentVisitorCoupons_targets (
      targetId mediumint not null auto_increment unique,
      primary key (targetId),
      isSitewide tinyint(1) not null,
      targetUrl varchar(500),
      displayThreshold tinyint(5) not null default 20,
      offerCutoff tinyint(5),
      fk_coupons_targets mediumint not null unique,
      foreign key fk_coupons_targets references frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons(couponId) on delete cascade
    );
```

​
This is my first attempt at foreign keys. What am I doing wrong above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your query and found out that you forget to mentioned Foreign Key Name in second create table syntax

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frequentVisitorCoupons_targets (
      targetId mediumint not null auto_increment unique,
      primary key (targetId),
      isSitewide tinyint(1) not null,
      targetUrl varchar(500),
      displayThreshold tinyint(5) not null default 20,
      offerCutoff tinyint(5),
      fk_coupons_targets mediumint not null unique,
      foreign key  fk_coupons_targets_frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons (fk_coupons_targets) references frequentVisitorCoupons_coupons(couponId) on delete cascade
    );
```

Comment: Works. Incredibly ugly also, I didn't think this had to be done. Will reconsider how to rename foreign keys now

Comment: Yup! you can drop table and re-create table with your required Foreign Key Name.

Comment: @SeanDezoysa there is no need to explicitly name the constraint.  Simply using the correct syntax -- which requires parentheses -- `foreign key (fk_coupons_targets) references ...` would also have resolved this.